# Dates not displaying correctly in Highcharts plot with irregular time data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm following the instructions [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time) to create a plot with irregular time data. However, as you can see in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a379ba3f/), the dates in the x-axis are displaying as `00:00:00.001`, `00:00:00.002`, etc.

```
$("#chart").highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        type: "datetime",
    },
    area: {
        visible: true
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            [new Date(1411014072), 1],
            [new Date(1412742072), 2],
            [new Date(1413606072), 3]
        ]
    }]
});
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First value in data must be UTC date

you are converting to datetime format
Try following code:

```
$("#chart").highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        type: "datetime",
    },
    area: {
        visible: true
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            [1411014072*1000, 1],
            [1412742072*1000, 2],
            [1413606072*1000, 3]
        ]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I also had to multiply the timestamp values by 1000.

Comment: @Undefined_variable: Please help me on [my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983248/need-help-in-plotting-a-chart-using-highcharts-in-angularjs)